# How to tell if a watcher function ran immediately in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, watch

In vue3, if I have something like this

```
watch(loading, (new_val, old_val) => {
    // how can I check if this function ran from the immediate being true, or when it changed after the immediate ran?
}, {immediate:true});
```

Is there something like this?

```
watch(loading, (new_val, old_val, options) => {
    console.log(options.immediate); // prints true the first time, and then false afterwords
}, {immediate:true});
```

Thanks

Comment: immediate is an option, not a state or something. If you need such a state then define it explicitly, i.e. ref(true)

Comment: try using watchEffect

Comment: so watchEffect runs immediately by default. Does it ever execute again though?

Answer (score 1):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Initially the old value is `undefined`.

You could also try `watchEffect`. It executes immediately and collects all reactive values it reads from as watch values inside the callback on the first execution. So there's no need to give it what to watch. That's determined automatically.

But if you don't mutate anything in the callback consider using `computed`. `watch` and `watchEffect` are used mainly for side-effects (mutations of any variables/data).

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, reactive} from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

const loading = ref(false);
const log = reactive([]);

setTimeout(()=>loading.value = true);

watch(loading, (val, old) => {
    
    if(old === undefined){
        // immediate
        log.push('immediate');
        return;
    }

    // not immediate
    log.push('not immediate');


}, {immediate:true});

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg">
  <div v-for="line in log">{{line}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Just cause old is undefined doesn't mean it ran the first time. I could have changed the value to undefined later and then back to some proper value.

Comment: @omega it would be a hack, not a proper way to do things, by default `ref()` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3, you can determine if a watcher function ran immediately by checking the flush option of the watcher. The flush option determines when the watcher is triggered and how it behaves.

```
watch(loading, (new_val, old_val) => {
    // Your code
}, {flush:sync});
```

By setting `flush` to `sync`, the watcher's callback function will be executed immediately during the component's setup, allowing you to determine if it ran immediately or not.

**Note :** Using `sync` flush option can have performance implications, as it runs the watcher immediately and synchronously. It is recommended to use it sparingly and only when necessary.

Comment: Sync is a variable here. What is the value of it and how do I check it in the function?